# Minimum operations to get from one number to another

Tags: code-golf, binary, graph-theory

Let's define a simple language that operates on a single 8-bit value.
It defines three bitwise operations (code explanation assumes 8-bit `value` variable):

- `!` Negate the least significant bit (`value ^= 1`)
- `<` Wrapping left-shift (`value = value << 1 | value >> 7`)
- `>` wrapping right-shift (`value = value >> 1 | value << 7`)

### Input:

Two 8-bit numbers, *a* and *b*. As they are 8-bit, you can alternatively take them as characters.

### Output:

The shortest way to get from a to b, with the three operations defined above.
You can return a string or an array of characters, or define a constant, distinct values for each operation and return an array of those (yes, you could also say `<` means `>` and `>` means `<`), but please explain your output format in your answer.

If there are multiple, equally long ways, you can output any or all of them.

### Rules:

- You can submit a program or function
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply
- The submission with fewest bytes **in each language** wins (no answer will be accepted)

Solutions without brute-forcing (or at least not only brute-forcing) might get my upvote.

### Test cases:

```
12, 13 => '!'
1, 2 => '<'
254, 253 => '<'
5, 5 => ''
98, 226 -> '<!>'
64, 154 -> '!>!>>>!>'
177, 164 -> '!>>!>>>!'
109, 11 -> '>>!>!>>'
126, 92 -> '!>!>!>!<' or '!>!>>!<!'
26, 85 -> '<!<<!<!<' or '<!<<!<!>' or '<!<<<!>!'
123, 241 -> '!>!<<!' or '>!<!<!'
236, 50 -> '<<!<!>' or '<<<!>!'
59, 246 -> '<<!>'
132, 95 -> '!<<!<!<!'
74, 53 -> '!>>>!>!'
171, 127 -> '<<!<<!<'
109, 141 -> '!>>>'
185, 92 -> '!>'
166, 201 -> '!<!>>>' or '<!>!>>'
77, 155 -> '<!'
124, 181 -> '!<<<<!>>' or '!>>>>!>>'
108, 85 -> '!<<<!<!<!<' or '!<<<!<!<!>' or '!<<<!<<!>!' or '!>>>!>!>!<' or '!>>>!>!>!>' or '!>>>!>>!<!'
185, 144 -> '<!<<!<!'
70, 179 -> '<<<!<!>' or '<<<<!>!' or '>>>>!>!'
```

[Here](https://tio.run/##fVHRToMwFH3nK85IEIi4DOKcWSif4A8YzRh0rgbaputmTPx3vC1saqL2hXLPOfeee6rf7V7JYhhEr5WxMLVsVZ9BWG6sUt0hCFq@g5D0rw23SZ1hm6FRLU/XAeicwFDDX3fKENL3RPeMkeCO2I0AY4hn8ZpEzwz5Bebdd0LpCQzJCWWJHFcolrcpPqhYVVj9oaomlSflxB7lK5LnxX3qVbTA0UhHY9gGgfMrnFna@oUnQuqjTdJpr5p6jWnM3WekFMu7sdP2X7TjkvDFmEqjjOGNpcKDktyX3vai45DKnsGvpL7Yjy7CKVO6kM3Lo8y1Ue2xsUk4K6swo700ry2jsamL@tfXerqMcO6uz/FrQ2yEUZshanFTITqEiDApY9D4eP6qhEw28XTx7TY/nE2u03QYisUn) is a program to generate a few more.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>100</s> <s>96</s> 86 bytes

```js
f=(a,b,[c,d,...e]=[a,''])=>c-b?f(a,b,[...e,c^1,d+1,c/2|c%2<<7,d+2,c%128*2|c>>7,d+0]):d
```

```html
<div oninput=o.textContent=f(a.value,b.value).replace(/./g,c=&gt;`&lt;!&gt;`[c])>a: <input type=number min=0 max=255 value=0 id=a> b: <input type=number min=0 max=255 value=0 id=b><pre id=o>
```

Somewhat slow breadth-first search without double-checking. Slightly more efficient 114-byte version:

```js
f=(a,b,c=[],[d,e,...g]=[a,''])=>c[d]?f(a,b,c,g):d-b?f(a,b,c,[...g,d^1,c[d]=e+1,d/2|d%2<<7,e+2,d%128*2|d>>7,e+0]):e
```

```html
<div oninput=o.textContent=f(a.value,b.value).replace(/./g,c=&gt;`&lt;!&gt;`[c])>a: <input type=number min=0 max=255 value=0 id=a> b: <input type=number min=0 max=255 value=0 id=b><pre id=o>
```

Both versions encode `<!>` as `012` but the snippets decode this for you. Edit: Saved 10 utterly useless bytes thanks to @RickHitchcock.

Comment: @wastl Thanks, I'd misremebered what the third symbol was.

Comment: Brilliant, and I think you can save 10 bytes:  `f=(a,b,[c,d,...e]=[a,''])=>c-b?f(a,b,[...e,c^1,d+1,c/2|c%2<<7,d+2,c%128*2|c>>7,d+0]):d`

Comment: @RickHitchcock Wow, those must be the most useless 10 bytes I've ever had in a single answer...

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 32 bytes

```
ṃ“ṙ1“ṙ-“¬8¦”
+⁹BḊ€0ÇẎv¥⁼ƭƒ@¥1#ḢÇ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzuZHDXMe7pxpCKF0gdShNRaHlj1qmMul/ahxp9PDHV2PmtYYHG5/uKuv7NDSR417jq09Nsnh0FJD5Yc7Fh1u/3@4/eikhztn/P8fbW6go2BobhkLAA)

**<**: `['ṙ', '1']`
**>**: `['ṙ', '-']`
**!**: `['¬', '8', '¦']`

Note: This is a function, that's why the footer is there.

Brute force. :(

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 105 bytes

Takes the 2 bytes in currying syntax `(a)(b)`.

Returns a string with:

- `0` = `!`
- `1` = `>`
- `2` = `<`

or an empty array if **a** is equal to **b**.

```javascript
a=>g=(b,m=1)=>(h=(n,s=[])=>n^b?s[m]?0:h(n^1,s+0)+h(n/2|n%2<<7,s+1)+h(n%128*2|n>>7,s+2):r=s)(a)?r:g(b,m+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZLJbsIwEIbvfYrhUMUuaYidOAuKzYMgKoWWVcWpCOqp707HrrMgORU5MKNvFv/zn@vvun2/nr5ur7r52N338l5LdZBkG14ko1KRoyQ6bOV6g4F@267a9WWzipdHot9Y2M5jOse/C/6jn3lV5ZhhNvPMePGCWaVMjtPlVbaU1HR1XR5Mc8Tut117AwmkDmFLQSpYR1G0R4hs6Sa61F9Em2wwU1WwnusNjc7NSZMgoE9P741um89d9NkciOlDgPEQgCWUwmKBNYEHAYYIcIdUHoSLNAQukn8QAGG6CIf4iLLAJjzrmsyUD8pwEhNpt6@aKaW8JMtzJLOB/EN9ZFwaDZgjDYioD@QZgiUfDcdfFUBzdavMKq@Ctq4Q/csq/Lo6F6khwsC7Jk9Qn5QN05H8qzJzvZN5YiaLuJs8njQ1B0Rp5mRDjVeLxBin7N7knuTtl6dmh2Q4hJp4YI5GYzwfLWtUmjgYGynhv1YhHq/lYzLUh8d9p8r2cpeYcAFYY4nhmt5bGZsWQ1@rtuqcYiXw7hMXY6dYM4y80sdqHNs79p0fPeliNY4nXGr1Ymn66FKvADGCednf6dFVwzrKnfr@Cw)
(with codes translated back to `!<>`)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 111 bytes

```python
l=[input()+('',)]
for(a,b,i)in l:a==b>exit(i);l+=[(x,b,i+y)for x,y in zip((a*2%256|a>>7,a/2|a%2<<7,a^1),'<>!')]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcrdCgIhEEDh@57CLhZnciCU/ij1RZYNXCgSxJUw0Nh3N7s7cL5U82uJqrVgRh/TJwMK4Jxw2jyXNziayaOPLFydMbN9FJ/B4y0IM0L5T1GxQ1aoss6@PgG4nRrU8bQ6a8/k9mp1g9K6510icW23HKfWpDoQkxf5Aw)

Comment: Since functions have to be reusable, I don't think you can use `exit` to produce output.

Comment: @Dennis I thought this would be covered by functions can output in the same way as full programs, but exiting isn't part oft the output, I guess. Does this mean functions can't output via exit code?

Comment: I think so. Allowing functions to output as full programs can doesn't override (imo) the rules for function submissions.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>201</s> <s>199</s> <s>198</s> <s>196</s> 193 bytes

- Saved two bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat); golfing `a/2+a*128` to `(a+2*a*128)/2` to `a*257/2`.
- Saved a byte; golfing `a*2+a/128` to `(a*2*128+a)/128` to `(257*a)/128` to `257*a>>7`.
- Saved <s>two</s> five bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat), golfing the return type.

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 193 bytes

```c
*P,D,Q,j;f(a,b,d){if(a&=255,Q&&a==b)for(Q=j=0;++j<D;printf("%d",j[P]));Q&&++d<D&&f(a^1,b,d,P[d]=1)&f(257*a>>7,b,d,P[d]=2)&f(a*257/2,b,d,P[d]=3);}F(a,b){for(D=Q=1;Q;D++){int p[D];f(a,b,0,P=p);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZFbb6MwEIWft7/CWNqAwdVig7nU2PtC@xy0b0lTiRKlm0jLRlHfovz27Jh7aBZQNLK/nDkzp3r8qKrr1V3SnBb0IHdOSd/plpz3UC0UF4IWi0Wp1DvZ/T05hTooX3reIcvl8bSvP3cO/r7F9LBebgiRgHreNssXC/j3GzNKdLnebhQjcMJF7JZax@MxN8elCxc/@HgaEHl5MT7I2fTMVaGYLGTueWCr/kTHdb7pjPp0qY6AX66/HHLuHSF4MJw@O9Xv8uSuxpvXOnvU5s4IS3clVyA6DFJh6q6Usi37p83sp6bOoOZdraEO7Cf4JXJUfK1Nr4c/5b4GDw/fwIl8cRDjFCEGszw72GosNQ@RA4EYEIg3RHaP4CKkiIvg/wRCwmiIhhiBKZEmoMGjVsPS@CsRQRcmwtaptrTWDTYSLI6BiHqiRW4JPzXTsoYwACD4pgvjERApH7rAm91ooIZIROc0g29GMB7ALCHrNQDBs40FRkP4rYZR0DMCidRoRD3RL2TSJTDJpa2PzsbttCgOTZeg34eZZTZtDNkyHg8@2lHmG2PDLPqOj0RMN4a/ZssimJb7nUY2qEydmuREv9N7Gtykn/QamVnJLH0/GXMxhNUmM3PKwnCaHJ758IGI024fQzBAXK7/AA)